# Perform a filter within a function call

Tags: java, java-8

Is there a way I could perform a filter within the steps of the following function call?

The following works fine but I wish to add a null/empty check on getResults which returns a list of Results object.

I could try to **.stream()** on it like **getResults().stream().filter()**;

But kind of pointless since getResults().stream() could potentially throw a null pointer already.

Also this returns a stream of Result. But I want to do a check on the List of Result itself, like:

```
.filter(CollectionUtils::isNotEmpty)
```

Is there a way to do this?

```
public MyFunc(Helper helper) {

    Function<String, HttpEntity<Request>> createRequestFunction = helper::createRequest;

    this.fetch = createRequestFunction
            .andThen(helper::getResponse)
            .andThen(Response::getQuery)
            .andThen(QueryResult::getResults)
            
            // I want to make a filter here .filter(CollectionUtils::isNotEmpty) to ensure
            // getResults (It is a List<Result> type) is not null or empty 

            .andThen(results -> results.stream()
                    .map(Result::getKey)
                    .filter(StringUtils::isNotBlank)
                    .map(s -> s.split("\\|"))
                    .filter(data -> data.length == 2)
                    .map(data -> data[1])
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`createRequestFunction` has type of `Function<String, HttpEntity<Request>>`

[Function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html) itself doesn't have a `filter` operation. It is possible to either append additional function via `andThen` or prepend via `compose`.

What is expected behaviour if  `QueryResult::getResults`  is `null`? What is the value of `this.fetch` should be?

One possible option is to wrap result of `QueryResult::getResults` into an `Optional`. Something similar to this:

```
this.fetch = createRequestFunction
            .andThen(helper::getResponse)
            .andThen(Response::getQuery)
            .andThen(QueryResult::getResults)
            .andThen(Optinal::ofNullable);
```

so the result of `this.fetch` is `Optinal<List<Result>>` and it is possible to execut different logic based on the fact if optional is empty or not.

e.g

```
return 
  this.fetch // Optinal<List<Result>>
  .getOrElse(Collections.emptyList()) // value of optional if it is not empty, or empty list otherwise 
  .stream()
                    .map(Result::getKey)
                    .filter(StringUtils::isNotBlank)
                    .map(s -> s.split("\\|"))
                    .filter(data -> data.length == 2)
                    .map(data -> data[1])
                    .collect(Collectors.toList())
```